# JS: functions return a 'sort of' empty array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, javascript-objects, es6-promise

I have this code that seems like it should work:

```js
import {
  flowerThumbsRef,
  flowersRef,
} from "../../../../utils/firebase/firebase";
import _ from "lodash";

// gets a list of all items in a firebase storage, builds an object, and pushes it into an array.
export const getAllImages = () => {
  let images = [];
  flowersRef.listAll().then((res) => {
    res.items.forEach((item) => {
      item.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
        images.push({
          name: item.name,
          link: url,
        });
      });
    });
  });
  console.log("allImages:", images);
  return images;
};

// gets a list of all items in a firebase storage, builds an object, and pushes it into an array.
export const getAllThumbnails = () => {
  let images = [];
  flowerThumbsRef.listAll().then((res) => {
    res.items.forEach((item) => {
      let newName = item.name.replace("_200x200", "");
      item.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
        images.push({
          name: newName,
          link: url,
        });
      });
    });
  });
  console.log("allThumbs:", images);
  return images;
};

//  executes previous functions in order to build an array of objects.
export const createItems = () => {
  const allImages = getAllImages();
  const allThumbs = getAllThumbnails();

  let items = [];
  if (allImages.length > 0 && allThumbs.length > 0) {
    allImages.forEach((item) => {
      let linkedThumb = _.find(allThumbs, (i) => i.name === item.name);
      items.push({
        itemId: item.name,
        mediaUrl: linkedThumb.link,
        metaData: {
          type: "image",
          link: item.link,
        },
      });
    });
  }
  return items;
};

const allItems = createItems();

console.log(allItems);
```

`flowersRef` and `flowerThumbsRef` point to a firebase storage location. There is no issue fetching the data.

In the first two functions, logging the return value shows what appears to be an empty array in the console until expanded. Here's a screenshot:
[Screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaEZZ.png)

and expanded:
[Screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlJB3.jpg)

and here is the third log:
[Screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhRNt.png)

I know I'm missing something.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: `listAll` is asynchronous. Your methods are returning before that call is completed. The console is clever enough to evaluate the array(s) when you expand them - at which point the async functions have probably completed

Comment: I thought so... How/where should I add async/await?

Comment: Take a look at the linked dupe, a lot to take in but it's all there