# Successive queries to firebase storage only fulfills the first call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, firebase-storage

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68940353/js-functions-return-a-sort-of-empty-array-of-objects).

I think I've solved the async problem. However, only the first function is getting fulfilled. I have log out both function calls but only the first displays the collection in the console. The second shows an empty array until I click to expand, then it shows the data.

Here is my code currently:

```js
import {
  flowersThumbRef,
  flowersFullRef,
} from "../../../../utils/firebase/firebase";


// gets a list of all items in a firebase storage, builds an object, and pushes it into an array and returns the array.
export const getAllImages = async () => {
  let images = [];
  const response = await flowersFullRef.listAll();
  response.items.forEach(async (item) => {
    const imgUrl = await item.getDownloadURL();
    images.push({
      name: item.name,
      link: imgUrl,
    });
  });

  return images;
};

// gets a list of all items in a firebase storage, builds an object, and pushes it into an array and returns the array.
export const getAllThumbnails = async () => {
  let images = [];
  const response = await flowersThumbRef.listAll();
  response.items.forEach(async (item) => {
    const imgUrl = await item.getDownloadURL();
    images.push({
      name: item.name,
      link: imgUrl,
    });
  });
  return images;
};

//  executes previous functions.
export const createItems = async () => {
  const allImages = await getAllImages();
  const allThumbs = await getAllThumbnails();

  console.log(allImages);
  console.log(allThumbs);
  
};

createItems();
```

I realize that this question is similar to the previous linked question, but I think I'm running into a different issue. Or there's some quirk of async JS that I'm missing.

Thanks!!

Comment: Also, please let me know how I can clarify the question title... I wasn't sure how to phrase it.

Answer (score 0):

So actually both are wrong :O. The reason the first seems ok, is because by the time you reach for it the promises have resolved, but if the way you coded this is not correct. The problem you are having is with the use of `.forEach`. `.forEach` is spinning up many `async` functions (this section right here `async (element) => {}`) and you are not awaiting each individual promise (PS: you wouldn't be able to with a `.forEach` loop). To fix this change the code to

```
import {
  flowersThumbRef,
  flowersFullRef,
} from "../../../../utils/firebase/firebase";


// gets a list of all items in a firebase storage, builds an object, and pushes it into an array and returns the array.
export const getAllImages = async () => {
  let images = [];
  const response = await flowersFullRef.listAll();
  for(let i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++){
    const item = response.items[i];
    const imgUrl = await item.getDownloadURL();
    images.push({
      name: item.name,
      link: imgUrl,
    });
  });

  return images;
};

// gets a list of all items in a firebase storage, builds an object, and pushes it into an array and returns the array.
export const getAllThumbnails = async () => {
  let images = [];
  const response = await flowersThumbRef.listAll();
  for(let i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++){
    const item = response.items[i];
    const imgUrl = await item.getDownloadURL();
    images.push({
      name: item.name,
      link: imgUrl,
    });
  });
  return images;
};

//  executes previous functions.
export const createItems = async () => {
  const allImages = await getAllImages();
  const allThumbs = await getAllThumbnails();

  console.log(allImages);
  console.log(allThumbs);
  
};

createItems();
```